# json adding dynamic childs to dynamic keys

Tags: json, dynamic, key

I am trying to format a bunch of data which I am able to retrieve in the format below. (I also put a readable version commented out)
I want to put each line in a ***json object*** in the way OUTPUT(see at the bottom) shows. But it only holds the last item's details whereas I want each item to be kept under the correct MGId and FGId values.

> MGId    MGName   FGId   FGName itemId itemName
>   6272440:Beverage:6272963:Coke:6274904:pepsi@@@

I use jsonObj[MGId][FGId][MIId], I was expecting this to create separate [MIId]'s under 
jsonObj[MGId][FGId].. Appearently I am missing something or it does not work in this way. 
Can anyone please tell me what is missing or any alternative way welcomes. thanks!!

```
/*
DATA READABLE FORMAT
6272440:Beverage:6272963:Coke:6274904:pepsi@@@
6272440:Beverage:6272963:coke:6274494:coco cola 1 lt@@@
6272440:Beverage:6272951:Milk:6274300:Skim 1 lt@@@
6272440:Beverage:6272951:Milk:6274130:Full Cream@@@
6272437:Food:6272919:Breakfast Menu:6274947:Bacon and Egg@@@
6272437:Food:6272915:Lunch Menu:6274766:Chicken Burger@@@
6272437:Food:6272915:Lunch Menu:6274922:Vegi Sandwich@@@
6272437:Food:6272915:Lunch Menu:6274900:Garlic Bread";
*/

var sampleData = "6272440:Beverage:6272963:Coke:6274904:pepsi@@@6272440:Beverage:6272963:coke:6274494:coco cola 1 lt@@@6272440:Beverage:6272951:Milk:6274300:Skim 1 lt@@@6272440:Beverage:6272951:Milk:6274130:Full Cream@@@6272437:Food:6272919:Breakfast Menu:6274947:Bacon and Egg@@@6272437:Food:6272915:Lunch Menu:6274766:Chicken Burger@@@6272437:Food:6272915:Lunch Menu:6274922:Vegi Sandwich@@@6272437:Food:6272915:Lunch Menu:6274900:Garlic Bread";
  var elements = sampleData.split("@@@"); 
  var jsonObj = {};
  var menuItemsArr = [];
  var previousMGId="";
  var previousFGId="";

  for(var i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {

     var nextMenuPack = elements[i];

     var nextMenuPackInnerHtml = nextMenuPack; //nextMenuPack.innerHTML;
     var nextMenuPackArr       = nextMenuPackInnerHtml.split(":"); 
     var MGId   = nextMenuPackArr[0];
     var MGName = nextMenuPackArr[1];
     var FGId   = nextMenuPackArr[2];
     var FGName = nextMenuPackArr[3];
     var MIId   = nextMenuPackArr[4];
     var MIName = nextMenuPackArr[5];
     console.log(MGName +"-"+FGName+"-"+MIName);


    jsonObj[MGId] = {}  ;
    jsonObj[MGId][FGId] = {};       
    //var jsonObj = {};
    jsonObj[MGId][FGId][MIId] = {       
                    "MGName" : MGName, 
                    "MGId": MIId,
                    "FGName": FGName,
                    "FGId": FGId,
                    "MIName" : MIName, 
                    "MIId": MIId

        };

}    


 document.write('<pre>'+JSON.stringify(jsonObj, null, "\t")+'</pre>');
```

OUTPUT

```
{
    "6272440": { //major group id
        "6272951": { //family group id
            "6274130": { // menuitem id - JUST LAST ONE, OTHERS OVERWRITTEN!
                "MGName": "Beverage",
                "MGId": "6274130",
                "FGName": "Milk",
                "FGId": "6272951",
                "MIName": "Full Cream",
                "MIId": "6274130"
            }
        }
    },
    "6272437": {
        "6272915": {
            "6274900": {// menuitem id - JUST LAST ONE, OTHERS OVERWRITTEN!
                "MGName": "Food",
                "MGId": "6274900",
                "FGName": "Lunch Menu",
                "FGId": "6272915",
                "MIName": "Garlic Bread",
                "MIId": "6274900"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Each time through the loop your reinitializing the elements to `{}`. You should only initialize the element if it doesn't already exist.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for having a look. I am initializing jsonObj[MGId]={}; AND  jsonObj[MGId][FGId] = {}; but adding MIId to jsonObj[MGId][FGId][MIId] each time. Maybe I am misinterpreting your help. Can you please give me a little example..

Comment: @Barmar: I guess I had to be told this to make it work..I got it right after adding the comment. Thanks a lot..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only initialize `jsonObj[MGId]` and `jsonObj[MGId][FGId]` if they're not already there.

```
jsonObj[MGId] = jsonObj[MGId] || {}  ;
jsonObj[MGId][FGId] = jsonObj[MGId][FGId] || {};       
//var jsonObj = {};
jsonObj[MGId][FGId][MIId] = {       
                "MGName" : MGName, 
                "MGId": MIId,
                "FGName": FGName,
                "FGId": FGId,
                "MIName" : MIName, 
                "MIId": MIId

    };
```

Comment: thanks again!! Your way looks very professinal..I also checked it with if(!(MGId in jsonObj)){jsonObj[MGId] = {};} AND if(!(FGId in jsonObj[MGId])){jsonObj[MGId][FGId] = {};}